# Win/Batch | Run all commands in the batch file at same time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch file:

```
@echo off 
ffmpeg -i source1 -o output
ffmpeg -i source2 -o output
ffmpeg -i source3 -o output
```

Problem is that when I launch my .bat file it runs first command only and won't start second one until the first one is finished and so on.

How do I trigger all three at same time when double clicking the .bat file? (which means they would need somehow to open on separate cmd window for each).

Comment: Try the **`start`** command, try it possibly with the **`/b`** option *and possibly without the addition of **`cmd /c`**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `start` command to create seperate windows.
You can use the `/k` to keep the window open or `/c` to close it after the command is done

```
start cmd /c ffmpeg -i source1 -o output
start cmd /c ffmpeg -i source2 -o output
start cmd /c ffmpeg -i source3 -o output
```